# How to change name App in fbsdk login React Native ('Project wants to Use facebook.com') iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, fbsdk

I use `ReactNative` `FBSDK` on `iOS` and Alerts when I press a button, **which is the name of the project,**

[image]

**How do I replace it?**

**Thank you.**

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61146747/ios-login-prompt-uses-bundle-name-unfollow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in `General` tab > `Display Name`
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In info.plist file find a property CFBundleName and replace it. Then see a result.