# iOS Login Prompt Uses Bundle Name Unfollow

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-unity-sdk

When using Unity Facebook SDK version 7.18 on iOS, the login permission prompt on iOS seems to be using the Bundle Name (CFBundleName) instead of Bundle Display Name (CFBundleDisplayname) in Info.plist.  The FacebookDisplayName is also set, but it is not using that.  Bundle Name by default is set to $(PRODUCT_NAME), but I don't think we'd want to change PRODUCT_NAME or Bundle Name.  What is the proper way to change or localize the app name shown in this dialog?

FB Login Dialog text:

"App Name" Wants to Use "facebook.com" to Sign In.

This allows the app and website to share information about you.

Cancel   Continue

Comment: i'm also having this problem, were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Same problem - no solution, the only way to update CFBundleName

Comment: Did anyone solve this without modifying CFBundleName? We have this problem too